# Website using Python Oracle and Javascript

Tags: python-2.7

I have a HTA tool that connects to oracle database. It's created using HTML,Javascript and oracle as backend. 
Javascript connects to oracle database using OLEDB drive. It pulls data and create dynamic rows. 
Tool is working but now am planning to convert it as Web Application. 
Being a DBA , am not that much familiar with Java and i thought i will explore options in Python. 
I have recently done a automation using Python and Selenium. So yes , i know bit of Python. But i have no idea about website using python.

I also don't want to change lot of code. I want javascript to do all the dynamic front-end stuffs. 
All i need is interface that can connect to oracle database and pull the information and pass it to javascript function. 
Can someone please guide to how to start with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python but if you don't want to change a lot of code, you may consider PHP. It's made to generate HTML code dynamicaly. 
It is dangerous to connect to your DB directly by using javascript. Every user can read the JS code in the page and event modify it(sending every value they want).

PHP is executed on the server, it mean that you can check and validate the received value before risking to corupt your DB.

That's why a PHP page between the JS and the DB is better. Python should be secure too but I think it's easier to use PHP because it's open source and well documented.

I wish you a good continuation!

Comment: Thanks for replying. But unfortunately , i can't use PHP for some organisational process.